# How to stop weblistener after the callback associated has been executed?

Tags: javascript, weblistener

I want to execute a function (named callback in this context) with a weblistener in Javascript. When the listener detect the good pattern it calls the callback function and this function never stop...
All of this is done with browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

The weblistener with browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener() detects the good pattern, call the associated function which make a GET request. Once it's done, the GET request is done again and again

```js
function getResponseFromSP()
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            console.log(xmlHttp.response);
            browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(getResponseFromSP);
            if(!browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(getResponseFromSP)){
       browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
     getResponseFromSP,
     {urls: ["https://example.com/policy"]}
    );
      }
     }
        }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://example.com:5000/policy", true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.responseType = 'json';
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

/*
Main part
*/

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
getResponseFromSP,
{urls: ["https://example.com/policy"]}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is to create a variable in the appropriate scope, check that it's false when you want to execute the function, but set it to true after execution.

```
var isDone = false;

// ...
if(!isDone) {
  // ... execute the function on the event being listened for here, then set
  isDone = true;
}
```